# New C++ GPP device in RedHawk2.0

Tags: redhawksdr

The release notes for RedHawk 2.0 say that the GPP device previously written in Python has been replaced with one written in "Written in C++, so it is more responsive".  But I find it still running in Python (according to ps command python is running GPP.py, and the $SDRROOT/dev/devices/GPP/GPP.spd.xml which also has softpkg version="1.10.0".  Was my installation defective and I still have parts of the 1.10 runtime system?  My IDE says 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry.  The GPP-2.0.0-3.el6.x86_64 DOES contain an ELF executable for GPP device.  But the rpm does not install unless I manually erase the GPP-1.10 pkg. Until erased yum says "nothing to do" for some reason.   I saw the source code in GPP-debuginfo but did not notice the executable in GPP-2.0.0 since it was all caps and looked like the directory.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like REDHAWK 2.0 was not properly installed on your system, the IDE and the framework/assets are separate and it is possible to get into a situation with conflicting versions depending on the installation steps taken.

Determining what version of REDHAWK you have installed can be determined in a handful of ways.  If you installed via yum or rpm you can check the versions of the rpms installed with:

rpm -qa | grep -i redhawk

The redhawk package, and redhawk-ide package should both be at 2.0. Note that the REDHAWK assets are versioned independently.

If you installed via source, you can use the package config files to obtain version information.  The framework keeps it's pc files in $OSSIEHOME/lib64/pkgconfig:

```
cat $OSSIEHOME/lib64/pkgconfig/ossie.pc
```

Will print out version information for the core framework installed. Depending on what is installed, there are pc files for the framework, bulkio, frontend, and burstio.

Comment: I upgraded from v1.10.0 following instruction in the manual.  rpm-qa|grep -i redhawk shows ALL packages are 2.0.0.*

Comment: It appears that the GPP device is NOT in a package containing "redhawk" and so is not listed using rpm -q | grep -i redhawk.  It appears to be in GPP-2.0.0-3.el6-x86_64.rpm.  If I list the contents using  
rpm -q -l -p GPP-2.0.0-3.el6-x86_64.rpm
I get only python files although they are different from those in 1.10.1 and ARE in a directory named "cpp" rather than "python.

Comment: It does not contain any ELF executables.  And if I try to yum install it again it says it is marking it as an update to GPP-1.10.1-3.el6.noarch but then "nothing to do" and  rpm -q show the GPP-1.10.1-3 package.  $SDRROOT/dev/devices/GPP/ does NOT contain a cpp directory.
I have installed RedHawk 2.0 as upgrades on two CentOS machines and both are as above.